# How to drop privileges in a script inside a non-interactive shell?

Tags: root, su, docker

I'm using Docker to create images that I can run as containers. I'm configuring my image all as the root user, including setting up volumes and other things. But once I've got all that configured I'd like to drop privileges to a non-privileged user for running my actual application. Here's what I'm trying to do currently:

```
# Do privileged stuff
su myuser -c "myapplicationcommand $@"
```

However, when these containers get deployed I'm apparently running in a non-interactive shell, because I get this error:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

So evidently the "su" command requires being run in an interactive shell. So my question is: How can I drop privileges from a non-interactive shell so that my application can run as a non-root user inside my Docker container?

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I don't see many good answers so adding this update in the hope that it helps others:

You can use the docker run -t and docker exec -it options to allocate pty in your docker exec session.
There is a good question and answer on this here:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8631

**This is more simple:** And you don't have to change the way you create or run the container. With docker exec you can simply use the -u  option to login to container as different users and avoid using su. e.g.

```
$ docker exec -u root -it small_hypatia bash

$ docker exec -u someone-else -it small_hypatia bash
```

Also see a more general answer on solving "su: must be run from a terminal" here. In particular it is useful to know how 'ssh -t' and 'ssh -tt' can be used. The python pty allocate cute hack also could be used to get su working for someone with the same problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944634/su-command-in-docker-returns-must-be-run-from-terminal/41872292#41872292

Answer (score 0):

Normally su would not have a dependency on a tty.  However, if there's something in the way of using su, maybe you could do the same with sudo instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
RUN adduser myuser
USER myuser
RUN foo
CMD bar
```

Both foo (during build) and bar (at runtime) will run as myuser.

Comment: And where would the OP put these lines?

Comment: I assume that since the author is building the docker images, he or she knows to put them in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I think the OP wants to do privileged stuff when the container launches rather than when building the docker container. An example would be mounting an NFS filesystem. After that is complete, whatever service the docker container is designed for should run as the non-root user.